# Repository Interface with (or without) IProgress

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I've got a repository interface (simplified example code):

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    Task<PersonDTO> Get();
}
```

With two implementations.

One for a direct connection to a database:

```
public SqlPersonRepository : SqlRepository, IPersonRepository
{
    public SqlPersonRepository(IDbConnectionProvider dbCon) : base(dbCon) { }

    public async Task<PersonDTO> Get()
    {
        // use dbCon and dapper to get PersonDTO from database
    }
}
```

And another one for remote access via web api:

```
public ApiPersonRepository : ApiRepository, IPersonRepository
{
    public ApiPersonRepository(IApiConnectionProvider apiCon) : base(apiCon) { }

    public async Task<PersonDTO> Get()
    {
        // use apiCon (contains base url and access token) to perform an HTTP GET request
    }
}
```

The interface makes sense here, because the server can use the `SqlPersonRepository`.  And the remote (native) client can use the `ApiPersonRepository`.  And for most all of the the use cases, this is all I need.

However, my application supports an extraction of a subset of data from the server so that the client application can run while offline.  In this case, I'm not just grabbing one person, I'm grabbing a large set of data (several to tens of megabytes) which many times will be downloaded over a slow mobile connection.  I need to pass in an `IProgress` implementation so I can report progress.

In those cases, I need an `ApiDatabaseRepository` that looks like this:

```
public ApiDatabaseRepository : ApiRepository, IDatabaseRepository
{
    public ApiDatabaseRepository(IApiConnectionProvider apiCon) : base(apiCon) { }

    public async Task<DatabaseDTO> Get(IProgress<int?> progress)
    {
        // use apiCon (contains base url and access token) to perform an HTTP GET request
        // as data is pulled down, report back a percent downloaded, e.g.
        progress.Report(percentDownloaded);
    }
}
```

However the `SqlDatabaseRepository` does NOT need to use `IProgress` (even if Dapper COULD report progress against a database query, which I don't think it can).  Regardless, I'm not worried about progress when querying the database directly, but I am worried about it when making an API call.

So the easy solution, is that the `SqlDatabaseRepository` implementation accepts the `IProgress` parameter, with a default value of null, and then the implementing method just ignores that value.

```
public SqlDatabaseRepository : SqlRepository, IDatabaseRepository
{
    public SqlDatabaseRepository(IDbConnectionProvider dbCon) : base(dbCon) { }

    public async Task<DatabaseDTO> Get(IProgress<int?> progress = null)
    {
        // use dbCon and dapper to get DatabaseDTO from database
        // progress is never used
    }
}
```

But that smells funny.  And when things smell funny, I wonder if I'm doing something wrong.  This method signature would give the indication that progress will be reported, even though it won't.

Is there a design pattern or a different architecture I should be using in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oversimplifying this, you basically have 2 options: having a consistent interface or not.

There are, of course other design patterns which might work here, (e.g.; some decorators and a factory method), but I believe them to be overkill.

If you stick to the general rule that consistent interface is desired, I think having a "not entirely implemented" callback technique isn't that bad. You could also consider just to implement it - or at least: make it return something which makes sense.

I would definitely avoid a construction with 2 different interfaces of some kind. Although sometimes this is the better option (when checking if something supports something), e.g.; testing if a hardware component is available - I see it as overkill in your scenario. It would also put more logic at the caller side, and unless you want to open a process-dialog screen only in this scenario, I would avoid it.

A last note: there are alternative progress report patterns such as using an event, or, passing in an optional callback method. This latter looks like your solution but is in fact a little different.

Still this faces you with the same issue in the end, but might be worth to consider.

---

There are many more solutions - but given the context you provided, I am not sure if they apply. And keep in mind, this is highly opinion based.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask an opinion based question...  Was hoping there was "a good solution"!  The client side UI is what uses the API version of the repository...  Using RX...  I suppose that I could raise an event and consume that with an Observable.FromEventPattern.  But I was hoping there was a way to design this (better) that I was missing!

Comment: Yes, it is a difficult one to answer... If you want to, there are more options - but the best I can come up with now is: just implement it in the Db version as well :-)

Comment: I ended up going with an implementation with an unused parameter in my case.  No need to add complexity for a one off case like this.  I'll only have to "work around" this issue in one or two of my repository interfaces, so not that huge of a deal.  But it still does smell funny!  Thanks!